# Adding a web service reference to a script# project

Tags: c#, web-services, script#

I'm trying to add a reference to a webservice that I have hosted in Microsoft Azure to a Script# project and I'm having a couple of issues with it.

At the moment I'm trying to do it as clean as possible so I'm working in a Script#>jQuery Script library project with nothing but the auto-generated code. If I right-click the solution > Add service reference > Advanced... > Add web reference and then compile I get an important amount of incompatibility errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'GeneratedCodeAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.CodeDom.Compiler' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs   15  38  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   2   The type 'System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\packages\ScriptSharp.0.7.5.1\tools\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll' C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs   15  38  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'GeneratedCodeAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.CodeDom.Compiler' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   26  30  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   4   The type 'System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\packages\ScriptSharp.0.7.5.1\tools\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll' C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   26  30  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'DebuggerStepThroughAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   27  25  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   27  25  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'DebuggerNonUserCodeAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs   27  37  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs   27  37  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   9   The type or namespace name 'SendOrPostCallback' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   33  34  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   10  The type or namespace name 'SendOrPostCallback' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   35  34  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   11  The type or namespace name 'SendOrPostCallback' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   37  34  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
Error   12  The type or namespace name 'SendOrPostCallback' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Axel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\ScriptSharpEmAirTest\Web References\net.azurewebsites.emair\Reference.cs   39  34  ScriptSharpEmAirTest
```

(There are actually 158 errors like that)

Evidently, compiling before adding the webreference goes smoothly and a console porject with the same webreference sees no issues.

Can you add webreferences to a scripsharp project? is there a specific procedure to follow?

Comment: This will not be possible, script# only supports a minimal subset of the .net Framework.

Comment: Is there like an official statement of sort that this isn't possible? maybe a comment by NikhilK?

Answer (score 0):

Same question as https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/414#issuecomment-39080016 ?

I commented there, but will copy here, for those who stumble on the same issue/question in the future:

> ... some contextual stuff to keep in mind.
>
> Script# is not about running .net code. Its about using c# language to
>   author script apps, and use the capabilities of scripting environments
>   (in browser, in node.js etc.). The answer to many of these "how do I
>   do x in script#" questions is the same as "how do I do x in
>   insert_your_script_environment".
>
> So, as mentioned, in a JavaScript client, you'd likely (or maybe I
>   should say ideally, since this isn't the case with WCF-based
>   implementations sometimes) work with a service with a simple REST API
>   that speaks JSON. The same applies in script#.